# Error thrown when using helper method getLayout()

Tags: react-native

I'm not sure what is wrong with the code. I'm using a helper method `getLayout()` to get my position of element to be animated. By default it should exist in the `ValueXY`according to this docs [http://browniefed.com/react-native-animation-book/api/GETLAYOUT.html.](http://browniefed.com/react-native-animation-book/api/GETLAYOUT.html).

Some help and explanation is much appreciated.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Animated } from 'react-native';

class Ball extends Component {
  conponentWillMount() {
    this.position = new Animated.ValueXY(0,0);
    Animated.spring(this.position, {
      toValue: { x: 200, y: 500 }
    }).start();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Animated.View style={this.position.getLayout()}>
        <View style={styles.ball} />
      </Animated.View>
    );
  }

}

const styles = {
  ball: {
    height: 60,
    width: 60,
    borderRadius: 30,
    borderWidth: 30,
    borderColor: 'red'
  }
}

export default Ball;`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a typo - `conponentWillMount` -> `componentWillMount`. This prevented your initialisation and meant that `this.position` was undefined, causing an error accessing `this.position.getLayout`.